# How to solve 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when trying to access api from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, xmlhttprequest, axios

I've seen a lot of topics on this error, but I'm very new to js and apis, so I couldn't really understand much, so I apologize for noob status.

I'm trying to access an api from sportradar. I'm testing it out on a simple react project created from create-react-app and using axios. When I console.log the data I get these errors: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/372w3g2b3F141t2P0K1G/Image%202018-09-04%20at%2011.33.38%20AM.png

I guess I can't access it from a local host? here is my function with the request:

```
getPlayerInfo() {
  const apiKey = "my-api-key";
  const playerID = "41c44740-d0f6-44ab-8347-3b5d515e5ecf";
  const url = `http://api.sportradar.us/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/players/${playerID}/profile.json?api_key=${apiKey}`;


  axios.get(url).then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backend support CORS, you probably need to add to your request this header:

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

Your code would be like this:

```
getPlayerInfo() {
  const apiKey = "my-api-key";
  const playerID = "41c44740-d0f6-44ab-8347-3b5d515e5ecf";
  const url = `http://api.sportradar.us/nfl/official/trial/v5/en/players/${playerID}/profile.json?api_key=${apiKey}`;
  const config = {
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
  };


  axios.get(url,config).then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you @sdn404! Well, it got rid of that error, but now it gives me 'Failed to load resource: Preflight...' error. If it helps, this is the info that is given from the site api sandbox: 'Request Headers: X-Originating-IP: 76.100.29.60
 
I added that request header in my code too. same error

Comment: here is the sandbox (down to player profile). Even if you don't have a key it should give you the important info https://developer.sportradar.com/io-docs

Comment: So I got in touch with their support team, and the api is not meant to be accessed directly. You're supposed to pretty much download the information yourself using curl/ruby/python and store it however you want. Not sure what the protocol is here. Should I still mark your answer as correct, or just delete this post?