# XMLHttpRequest for Riot API with Next React App, got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, cors

I want to get riot data from Riot API.

But I got error  `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`

So, I tried to set `package.json` proxy setting to https://kr.api.riotgames.com

[image]

But I still got this kind of Error.

[image]

```
const getSummonerData = async () => {
    console.log(summonerName)
    const apiKey = "-----------------------------------------"
    const url = `/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key=${apiKey}`
    const data = await axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

    console.log("data : ", data)
}
```

Finally I tried this way (adding `headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}` config to axios):

[How to solve 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when trying to access api from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171178/how-to-solve-access-control-allow-origin-error-when-trying-to-access-api-from)

But, same error still occurs.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, instead of links, post the code or pictures of what you are referencing. Links can go down, expire, or be blocked in certain regions, so it is always better to include code instead of links.

Comment: @DeathWaltz Thank you, Sorry about that!

Comment: Much better! Thank you.